# Ansible variable skipping no matter what

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook and in the tasks I need to check if a package is installed, specifically `containerd.io`.

```
- name: test package installed
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Gather the package facts
      package_facts:
        manager: auto

    - name: print found
      debug:
        msg: 'containerd.io found'
      when: "'containerd.io' in ansible_facts.packages"

    - name: print not found
      debug:
        msg: 'containerd.io not found'
      when: not "'containerd.io' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

But when I run said playbook (when the package is not yet installed), it skips it no matter what.  Both `print found` and `print not found` get skipped.

How can they both get skipped when they are the inverse of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your second conditional wrong:

```
    - name: print not found
      debug:
        msg: 'containerd.io not found'
      when: "'containerd.io' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```